# front page of thesis

Tags: thesis, front-matter

To produce front page of the thesis a separate .tex file should be created?

After reading several already asked question regarding the same I found that for the front page a separate `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` should be used. If this the case then I need to use another `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` for the chapters of my thesis?

Comment: Where have you read this? Do you have any links?

Comment: Sorry I could me miss understood. Kindly brief me about it. Both the front page and all chapters should be within one begin{document} and \end{document} ?

Comment: @Higgs Yes, the front page and chapters should all be within one `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` pair.

Comment: As far as I know there is one exception: using `standalone` class in child document and `standalone` package in parent document. In this case you have a `\begin{document} [...] \end{document}` for each file. This gives you different advantages and I really don't know why the most cited solutions to modular documents are `\input` and `\include` while almost nobody cite `standalone`.

Comment: @giusva Because it's mostly sufficient for a thesis. But if you think the standalone option is that great of an advantage you could still answer.

Comment: @TeXnician The fact is that most of the LaTeX's user have seen in real life have used it only for the thesis. The main advantage of `standalone` is, IMHO, the reusability of the code. I'm not one of those user but I discovered the the `standalone` package and its potential a long time after I started using LaTeX.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: By the way, you should read an introduction. You are posting very basic LaTeX questions that have nothing to do with a thesis in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write all your thesis - or even a book - with only one file: no class files, no separate chapters, figures, tables, bibliography and so on.

It's not imperative to structure your work in multiple files... but you should.

There are several reasons to do it and pretty much no reason not to. If you separate your TiKz figures and your tables you got rid of a lot of lines of code that make it hard for you to focus on the main content of your thesis, that is the text. Works with individual files for each chapter make it easy for you to keep track of your progress without messing with your main file. Working with separate file decrease the time of your compilation (this fact doesn't apply to imported files) because you don't have to recompile from scratch each time.

The title page, if it isn't the default one, usually has a lot of lines of codes so it's best to keep it separate.

Besides the other two mentioned methods (`include` and `input`) I would suggest the use of `standalone` package for the parent file and `standalone` class for child files. In this way, the child file (it could be a `tabular`, a `tikzpicture`, a chapter of your thesis, etc.) would be compilable on its own without the main file. This means that you could easily move your child files from one document to the other without worries of packages and so on (well, maybe sometimes conflicts between packages can happen). This also means that you have only to load the package you need only for a part of the document only in the corresponding child and that makes it easier for you do not have a final document with a lot of packages loaded without needs.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You are absolutely free how you structure your projects (e.g. your thesis). There is no necessity to use different documents (with multiple document environments) nor do I know anyone who would recommend it.

How I would do it:

- Use a separate TeX file for the title page if it's graphics heavy (TikZ etc., just to shorten your main code) which you `\input` later.
- Use a separate TeX file for each of your chapters (this is also to shorten your code) and then `\include` them, because you'll be able to have a valid toc without compiling the whole document every time.

Comment: I would recommend to use a standalone titlepage. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation